# Highlight multiple matches without removing previous context

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Suppose I want to make a syntax highlighting script to work with files with the following hypothetical format:

```
blah # blahA1B2 bla
asdf A11B453 # qwert
aaa A0B0 bbb @
```

That is, lines with arbitrary text, but somewhere in the line I have a string with the format `A\d\+B\d\+` (`A` immediately followed by a number, immediately followed by `B`, and then another number).

Furthermore, suppose that I highlight the whole line based on another pattern (in the example I'll make it clear).

**What I want** is to highlight **only** the numbers within the pattern `A[0-9]\+B[0-9]\+`, **without** removing the current highlight from the `A` and `B`.

The following script almost solves my problem:

```
syn match Type '.*#.*'
syn match Macro '.*@.*'
syn match Number '[AB]\zs\d\+\ze'
```

What it does:

- Highlight with green lines that have a `#` (this part is ok).
- Highlight with purple lines that have a `@` (this part also is ok).
- Highlight the number following A or B (this need improvement).

The problem with my script is that it also highlights `A2` and `B3`, but they should be together to be highlighted.

I've also worked a bit with the `contains` and `containedin`, but with no success.

Comment: Work harder at understanding `containedin`.  Add a pattern for `A11B453`, then make the `[AB]\zs\d\+\ze` contained in it.

Comment: I did that also, this violates the condition of not removing the previous highlighting from A and B.

Comment: ... Which is why you make the pattern transparent.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `transparent` was the missing piece of the puzzle, as @Sato points out.

The final script would be something of this sort:

```
syn match Type '.*#.*'
syn match Macro '.*@.*'
syn match pattern 'A\d\+B\d\+' transparent contains=num
syn match num '[AB]\zs\d\+\ze' contained
hi def link num Number
```

Without the `transparent`, A and B would lack highlighting.

For some reason adding a `containedin=pattern` in num's line won't work, but I didn't bother finding out why.

Comment: Nope, this still highlights all `A=number` and `B=number`.  You have to use `contained`, not just `contains`.  And you can safely forget about `containedin`.

Comment: Right, I've added the `contained` part.

Comment: Yes: without `contained` the `num` pattern is also matched at top level.